# GPIO and pinouts?

Tags: stm32, gpio, nucleo

I am about to start a project with an STM32 in my internship and the board that I am supposed to be using is the STM32H750-dk. I am new to all of this and was told get myself familiar with the microcontroller boards and programming and other concepts related to the microcontroller.

Most of the programming tutorials in the internet are done on Nucleo boards and not on other dev boards. The Nucleo boards have Arduino connectors and alongside them they have their STM32 GPIO pins on the board (like on the Nucleo-64 which has many other male pins along with female Arduino pins). The board that was assigned to me has, according to the user manual, 168 GPIO pins, but the board has only Arduino connectors and no other pin headers to connect to.

How do I use the 168 GPIO pins without any pin headers?

Comment: Have you read the associated documentation for the board? With development boards, the manufacturers generally try to tell you everything you need to know. Read the doc, look at the schematics and if there are still questions, you can ask something specific here. I’ll give you a hint - the board has a display and other peripherals that will consume a fair bit of gpio.

Comment: Yes, dozens of GPIO pins are used to drive the display, Ethernet, interface with flash and RAM, etc. Many others are just not connected. How many do you actually need? Do you need any of those peripherals?

Comment: @Kartman, The schematics don't really tell where the GPIO's are connected to. They only show the ARDUINO connectors on the board. Let's say I want to use more than the GPIO's available on the board, what do I do then?

Comment: Table 17 of um2488 (the user manual) has a list of all the pin assignments without having to read the schematic. Anyways, by now you should have downloaded the schematics and board layouts. Your supervisor is probably reading this and shaking his head as a simple Google would’ve answered your question in seconds.

Answer (score 0):

I am writing this from beginner’s point of view, since i was also at your stage a year ago.

Case 1: If you are not familiar with stm controllers start with cheapest one which is stm32f103ref8t6 IC ( board is called blue pill) there are tonns of tutorial you can refer don’t go too deep just understand how it works.

Case 2: If you have atlest blinked an led on stm32, you are ready to go further,

Steps to work on any gpio pins ( applicable to most of stm32 series of mcu from st’s ecosystem) :

Best thing about ST is that, they have well classified documentation ( this is what you need to refer) for  STM32H750-dk board ( technically devlopment kit).

This link contains all you want
https://www.st.com/en/evaluation-tools/stm32h750b-dk.html#documentation

Go to  “CAD Resources”  tab, then go down to “Schematic Pack” (A) and get  board schematic  file.
Go to  “Documenation”  tab, then go down to “User Manuals” (B) and get  the board datasheet file.

(A) schematic file shows the pinout of mcu ( from this you will get to know where each pin of mcu is connected on your board.
(B) show all connectors  and peripherals assigned to those connectors on your board.

Now
“How do I use the 168 GPIO pins without any pin headers?”
-> you can’t use all 168 pins, since most pins are assigned to a particular peripheral (ref. UM2488, “Figure 3,4 and 5”) but you use it to connect that specific periferal ( I2c , SPI, UART, USB-OTG,LCD) .

But to get started with board, you can use User Button (marked B1 connected to PC13 on board ) and user LED’s ( marked-LD6, LD7and LD8 connected PI13, PJ2 and PD3 on board)

You can also use arduino connectors CN2, CN3, CN6, and CN7 (ref UM2488, Table 8)
the table shows port pins ( also these are available as female headers on the back of board.

For coding its same as any bluepill or nucleo or discovery board.